# Getting a SUM based off the column's relationship with another column (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, case

So let's say you have the following data representing employees within a company.  Column one is their unique ID, column 2 is the ID of their supervisor, and column 3 represents whether or not the employee is over 21.  (Y means they are over 21, N means they are not)

```
    |Employee ID |Supervisor ID|Over21|
    -----------------------------------
    |1           |1            |Y     | 
    |2           |1            |N     |
    |3           |1            |Y     |
    |4           |2            |Y     |
    |5           |2            |Y     |
    |6           |3            |N     |
    |7           |3            |N     |
```

So, if I wanted to find the number of employees that are over 21, I could do that pretty easily with:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Over21] IS 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

But let's say you want to find **the number of supervisors that have an employee that is over 21**. (In this example it would be 2).   I've been racking my brain trying to figure out a way to write out a way to find that but I've been struggling so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count (distinct Supervisor)
from your_tab
where Over21 = 'Y';
```

Without where:

```
select count (distinct case when Over21 = 'Y' then Supervisor else null end)
from your_tab;
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks that answers the question.  I guess I didn't ask the correct question though, because I'm making a statement with multiple other counts, so I can't have the where clause affecting all of them.

Thanks for the answer though since it answered my question, I will mark as correct.